# For Loop containing Async-Call

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have a problem with the following code not functioning...

```
func getThatImage() {
    for imageurl in self.imageUrl    {
        self.group1.enter()
        print("1:counter: \(counter)")
            self.dbFunctions.downloadImage(urlPath: imageurl, completion: { retrievedImage in
                print("2:counter: \(self.counter)")
                self.gameGroups[self.counter].icon = retrievedImage.0!
                print(self.gameGroups[self.counter].iconUrl)
                self.counter += 1
                print("3:counter: \(self.counter)")
                self.group1.leave()
            })
    }

    self.group1.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toNavController", sender: self)
    })

}
```

When the images in the destinationViewController from the Array `gameGroups` get presented, only the last image in the array get presented. It iterates through the array `imageUrl` until the last element of the array, then the async-block gets executed. So far I tried with moving `group1.enter()` inside the completion but that didn't help either. Any ideas why this is happening? Did I misunderstand how to use `DispatchGroup`?

The Output of the above code is:

```
1:counter: 0
1:counter: 0
1:counter: 0
2:counter: 0
Optional("static/number-3-256.png")
3:counter: 1
2:counter: 1
Optional("static/number-3-256.png")
3:counter: 2
2:counter: 2
Optional("static/number-3-256.png")
3:counter: 3
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you happen to solve this? I am having the *exact* same issue!

Comment: Yes I did! Do you still need it?